# Concatenating a string using Win32 API

Tags: c, string, winapi, visual-c++, concatenation

What's the best way to concatenate a string using Win32? If Understand correctly, the normal C approach would be to use `strcat`, but since Win32 now deals with Unicode strings (aka `LPWSTR`), I can't think of a way for `strcat` to work with this.

Is there a function for this, or should I just write my own?

Comment: There is wcscat() and wcsncat()

Comment: @roymustang86 that should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: @Seth: Not really, since they aren't Win32 APIs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`lstrcat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647487.aspx) comes in ANSI and Unicode variants.  Actually `lstrcat` is simply a macro defined as either `lstrcatA` or `lstrcatW`.

These functions are available by importing `kernel32.dll`.  Useful if you're trying to completely avoid the C runtime library.  In most cases you can just use `wcscat` or `_tcscat` as roy commented.

Also consider the `strsafe.h` functions, such as [`StringCchCat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647518.aspx)  These come in ANSI and Unicode variants as well, but they help protect against buffer overflow.

Comment: lstrcat is a "banned" API internally at Microsoft because it cannot be safely used (lstrcat catches exceptions which can introduce security bugs).  Stick to StringCchCat.

Comment: @Larry: I wouldn't use it with tainted data, but how is it unsafe if you've checked that the output buffer is large enough?

Comment: Even if the buffer isn't tainted, there's still a risk - if for some reason the source or destination of the copy is corrupt, your app won't crash which means you won't find the bug which caused the corruption.

Comment: Btw StringCchCatEx has the added benefit that it returns a pointer to the end of the string which can be a perf win.

Comment: This article says that strcat() is unsafe: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: @EdwardFalk: "unsafe" is too nebulous a word to be helpful.  `strcat` is perfectly fine (doesn't discard hardware exceptions the way that `lstrcat` does) if you do a correct buffer overflow check first, but buffer overflow checking is tricky and most programmers won't get it correct.  That's why in my answer I recommend the `strsafe.h` functions.