# How to concat LPWSTR in C code

Tags: c, string, string-concatenation

I have two variables as below In my C program

```
 PWSTR linkName = L"fileName";
     PWSTR targetFile = L"pathName";
```

I want string like `"mklink /j "+linkName+" "+targerFile` i.e., I want to concatenate the above two.

Can any one tell me how?

Comment: If you have the option of using `C++`, you can use [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421139/concatenation-of-lpwstr-strings). If you have the option of using Win32 API, you can use [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440768/concatenating-a-string-using-win32-api).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want something like [wsprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx)

Allocate a new buffer for your wchar_t which will hold the result

```
wsprintf(newBuf, "%s%s", linkName, targetFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **wcscat**. Visit this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282.aspx